# Hide the page number if there is only 1 page in the document

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

My goal is to create a block for the signature and page number in a contract. For standard cases it should look like this:

[image]

But for the last page there should be no "Borrower" block. If there is only 1 page there should be no page number either.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{pageslts,refcount}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\ifnum\getpagerefnumber{VeryLastPage}=\value{page}\else
    Borrower \makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
    \vspace{2mm}
    \fi
%    \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{VeryLastPage}=1 <- problem
    Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}
%    \fi  <- problem
  }% Right footer
}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

I managed to fulfill the first requirement, but when I added the condition for the 2-nd one: `\ifnum\getpagerefnumber{VeryLastPage}=1` it it still shows the page number.

How can I hide the page number if there is only 1 page in the document.

Comment: The text should only show if the last page is *not* one, so you should add an `\else` after the condition (i.e., `\ifnum\getpagerefnumber{VeryLastPage}=1\else`).

Comment: @Marijn It worked, thx.